# How to write test with Outlet of React-Router-DOM v6?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm writing test with Jest and I encounter problem with `Outlet` from React-Router-DOM.

I have a component named `Preferences` and it is nested inside another router. Inside `Preferences` I have 5 child routes:

```
{/* Route for Preference. */}
<Route
  path="/preferences"
  element={<LazyComponent component={'LazyPreferences'} />}
>
  <Route index element={<LazyComponent component={'LazyAccount'} />} />
  <Route
    path="accounts-1"
    element={<LazyComponent component={'Account-1'} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="accounts-2"
    element={<LazyComponent component={'Account-2'} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="accounts-3"
    element={<LazyComponent component={'Account-3'} />}
  />
</Route>
```

At the `Preferences` component, I'm using `Outlet` from React-Router-DOM like this:

```
const Preferences = () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <PreferencesMenu />
      <Outlet />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

When I mock the `Preferences` component, it just displays `Preferences` navigation. How can I deal with child component like Account-1, ...?

here is my test

```
describe('Preferences screen with Account', () => {
    beforeEach(cleanup)

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })

    test('Click on the Account option, router will navigate to /accounts', async () => {

          const wrapper = mountWithApp(<Preferences />)

        expect(wrapper).toContainReactText('ACCOUNT')

        await userEvent.click(screen.getByText('ACCOUNT'))
        expect(mockedUseNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/preferences/accounts')
      })
})
```

Comment: I think we need more context here. Can you [edit] to clarify what any specific issue or problem is that you face, and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: hi @DrewReese, the problem I face with is the component inside route of Preferences doesn't display. As I guess, because it is inside Outlet of React Router DOM, so I think we need to mock that component to display. But I have no idea to do that

Comment: What are you trying to *unit test*? The test code you are using is as important as the UI code it is testing. This is what I mean by a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since the navigation menu is being displayed, you can just create a click event on menu items to navigate to your outlet routes. So you can test whether outlet components appear on the document or not, after you navigate.

To make use of `<Outlet />` component, you need to render your `<Preferences />` with `<MemoryRouter />`:

```
 render(
    <MemoryRouter>
       <Preferences />
    </MemoryRouter>
 )
```

Also, you seem to have been using custom matchers and functions, you could just use `render` and `getByText` / `getByRole`

Comment: I have set click event and it works correctly, however expected component doesn't appear

Comment: Components using react-router-dom's components/elements should be rendered with Router components in tests. It would be better for our understanding if you add the test function to your question as well.

Comment: I have updated the test function to my question, please help me review it. Thank you.

Comment: Actually my custom matchers and functions (mouthWithApp) has contained MemoryRouter already.